# The inverse of $(I-A)$ and the spectral radius of a nonnegative $A$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Suppost that $A$ is a [nonnegative matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix), and let denote the [identitiy matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) with $I$ and the [spectral radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$ with $\rho(A)$. Note that because $A$ is nonnegative according to the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) $\rho(A) = \lambda_\max(A)$.

**Statement.** The following two are equivalent

1. $I-A$ matrix is invertible and $(I-A)^{-1}$ is a nonnegative matrix
2. $\lambda_\max(A) < 1$.

Note that because of the statement we also know that the [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) of $A$ convergent.

**Question.** How could we prove this statement?

Comment: Can we use the Neumann series to prove the statement?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It is better to show it without Neumann series, but feel free to post any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\lambda_{\max}<1$. Then $\rho(A)=\lambda_{\max}=1-\tau$, $\tau\in(0,1)$ and $\|A^k\|< (1-\tau/2)^k$ for $k$ sufficiently large. Thus the Neumann series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k = (I-A)^{-1}
$$ 
converges. As $A$ is non-negative, $A^k$ is non-negative, and by the series representation $(I-A)^{-1}$ is non-negative.

If $\lambda_{\max}=1$ then $I-A$ is not invertible.

Assume $\lambda_{\max}>1$ and that $I-A$ is invertible. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $(1-\lambda)^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $(I-A)^{-1}$.
By Perron-Frobenius theorem there exists a non-negative eigenvector $x$ such that
$Ax = \lambda_{\max}x$. This implies
$(I-A)^{-1}x = \frac1{1-\lambda_{\max}}x$. Since $\lambda_{\max}>1$ it follows $\frac1{1-\lambda_{\max}}<0$. As $x\ge0$ it follows that $(I-A)^{-1}$ cannot be non-negative.